# Importing multiple CSV files into variables with the same name

Tags: python, csv, import

There are as many as 1440 files in one directory to be read with Python. File names have a pattern as

```
HMM_1_1_.csv
HMM_1_2_.csv
HMM_1_3_.csv
HMM_1_4_.csv
...
```

and for `HMM_i_j_.csv`, `i` goes from 1 to 144 and `j` goes from 1 to 10.

How can I import each of them into a variable named `HMM_i_j` similar to its original name?

For instance, `HMM_140_8_.csv` should be imported as variable `HMM_140_8`.

Comment: With the other words what you need is to declare a variable **name** `dynamically`. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: What have you tried already? Include your non-working code. If you haven't even made any code, then I suggest reviewing the Python docs on CSV reader. For variable assignment, you can load those CSVs into an object which has keys that follow from the indices, e.g. `dict["144_1"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using pandas and a dictionary. Here is the script that would probably do what you want.

In order to access to a specific csv file in python environment, just use i.e csv[HMM_5_7].

```
import pandas as pd
csv = {}
for i in range(1, 145):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        s = 'HMM_{}_{}'.format(i,j) 
        csv[s] = pd.read_csv(s+'.csv')
```

**Or:** (shorter)

```
d = {}

for i in range(1440):
    s = 'HMM_{}_{}'.format(i//10+1,i%10+1)
    d[s] = pd.read_csv(s+'.csv')
```

Or  a less readable one-liner:

```
d = {'HMM_{}_{}'.format(i//10+1,i%10+1):
     pd.read_csv('HMM_{}_{}.csv'.format(i//10+1,i%10+1)) for i in range(1440)}
```

Comment: You don't need pandas, there is a built-in csv module.

Comment: @LouisSugy thank you. Just wrote the first thing came to mind.

Comment: Thank you, Anton and kaanyilmaz, for the well-written answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting them in variables with this name, you can create a dictionary where the key is the name minus '_.csv" and the value is the content of the file.

Here are the steps, I let you figure out how to exactly do each step:

- Create an empty dictionary
- Loop i from 1 to 144 and j from 1 to 10
- If the corresponding file exists, read it and put its content in the dictionary at the corresponding key